# create custom url for users that expires php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, custom-url

I have a form that every user who is registered must use within a month and when a user registers they need a custom url to complete that form. Each user needs to have a unique url for the form which will expire every 4 weeks. Then a new link is generated once the form has been completed.

I have seen a number of scripts that could help however not had any luck.

What im looking for is similar to a lost password random url which expires within 6 weeks but the random url needs to be attached to that user as the user will receive the link in an email

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: `<?php // code goes here ?>` There you go. The rest is up to you.

Comment: append time() to query parameter of URL, if NOW() - query parameter > 4 weeks, form dead

Comment: If you use a framework like Laravel you can potentially get this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table that store the user_id, the current date and a unique token. So via a GET parameter you can get the unique token. After 4 weeks, the entry will be removed.